# Can C#7 tuples be destructured in parameter lists?

Tags: c#, syntax, tuples, destructuring, c#-7.0

I'm confused by C#7 tuples and frankly the very light amounts of documentation around them.

For example I know from examples that I can do this

```
var tup = (a: 1, b: 2);
(var a, var b) = tup;
```

But that usage is literally the only example I keep seeing. From experience in other languages, I know that far more common is to want to destructure tuples incoming into parameter lists.

so something like

```
test(tup);
```

...

```
int ((int a, int b)) => a + b;
```

But I can't quite figure out the syntax nor find any examples - is this possible at all?

Comment: `public void myFunc((int a, char b) MyData){ Console.WriteLine(MyData.a); Console.WriteLine(MyData.b);  }` -> `myFunc((33, 'a'));`

Comment: @Gusman but that's explicitly *not* destructuring, you're just redefining the type in the parameter list

Comment: What you mean with "destruction"? You mean "decompose" the tuple? If you want to decompose the tuple into parameters, then why use at all a tuple instead of plain parameters?

Comment: @Gusman The question is about destructuring, not destroying, as in the removing of structure, and it's a suitable term here.

Comment: Good thought @GeorgeMauer trying to get something here https://dotnetfiddle.net/pVZuye but no joy.

Comment: Because you're typically piping data output from one function into another - one fn returns a tuple, and you pass into another that wants to use certain props. Its by far the most common use case for destructuring that I've seen. As an example of where I want it *right now* is in building an instance of `ILookup<>` where I build up something with an array of tuples but want to destructure in the `ToLookup()` lambda

Comment: Sorry man, I've been reading wrong all the time the question, I was reading "destructing" instead of "destructuring"

Comment: No problem, thanks for the involvement :)

Comment: isn't the problem in the fact that you define lambda as ((int a, int b)) => a + b instead of ((int a, int b) c) => c.a + c.b; i.e. forgetting to declare the name of the tuple?

Comment: Take a look at my fiddle @GeorgeMauer I think I've got something https://dotnetfiddle.net/pVZuye I you like it I can post it as an answer

Comment: Well in fact I wouldn't post this as answer, I think this is a duple https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589540/in-c-sharp-7-is-it-possible-to-deconstruct-tuples-as-method-arguments/41590136

Comment: @kblok so as I pointed out to Gusman, that's not destructuring, you're just re-declaring the tuple in the parameter list (which you have to do anyways)

Comment: Sounds like the answer is no....

Comment: @GeorgeMauer The question specifically asks the same thing, and the answer specifically says it's no possible (in addition to also presenting an alternative that you've mentioned you don't want) so it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy I know, I was the first person to vote to close it as a dupe

Comment: The only contexts (in C# 7.0) where deconstruction is supported are: deconstruction assignment and deconstruction foreach.
In the future, deconstruction may be supported in more contexts. For example, LINQ let (`let (x, y) = ...`), or out variables (`M(out var (x, y))`), or lambda parameters (syntax TBD).
There was also discussion about splatting tuples into method invocations (also not supported in C# 7.0).
Look at the issues on csharplang repo for more details on those topics.